# WooCommerce Shipping API functions

Tags: php, wordpress, api, mobile, woocommerce

I have **WooCommerce** Conditional shipping & Payment, Table rate plugin installed. I am trying to create an `API` functions for mobile to get shipping methods from ***WordPress WooCommerce***.

i have the 2 plugin install with the settings below Woocommerce conditional shipping & payment
[image]

and table rate shipping

[image]

let say i can get the basic default woocommerce shippings and calculation correct. but how can i get the condition restrictions from the 2 plugin?
i have no idea which methods in these 2 plugin to use to get the conditions.
[image]

If Anyone have done this before or have some clues please helps Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply this 3 line of code it will get available shipping methods for you from cart items

```
    global $woocommerce;
    $cart = wc()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
    $shippingMethods =  wc()->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package($cart);
    return $sm;
```