# WooCommerce Get All Shiping Method Calculated API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to create an API functions for mobile to get shipping methods from WordPress WooCommerce. This is my code:

```
    public function get_shipping($request){
        $params = (array) json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
        $state =  $params['state'];
        $country =  $params['country'];
        global $woocommerce;
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
        foreach ($params['line_items'] as $item) {
           if((int) $item["variation_id"] > 0 ){
               $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(
                   (int)  $item["id"],
                   (int) $item["quantity"],
                   $item["variation_id"]);
           } else {
               $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart(
                   (int)  $item["id"],
                   (int) $item["quantity"]);
           }
        }

        $package =  $woocommerce->cart->get_shipping_packages();
        $delivery_zones = (Array) WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
        $new_delivery_zones = Array();
        foreach ($delivery_zones as $zone) {
            $z_object =  (Array) $zone;
            $new_shippings = Array();
            foreach ($z_object["shipping_methods"] as $shipping) {
                $s_item = Array();
                $objects = (Array) $shipping;
                foreach ($objects as $key => $value) {
                    if($key != "instance_form_fields") {
                        $s_item[$key] = $value;
                    }else{
                        $f_item = Array();
                        $new_form_fields = Array();
                        $form_fields = (Array) $value;
                        foreach ($form_fields as $keyi => $valuei) {
                            $valuei["name"] = $keyi;
                            $f_item[$keyi] = $valuei;
                            array_push($new_form_fields, $valuei);
                        }
                        $s_item["instance_form_fields"] = $new_form_fields;
                    }
                }
                array_push($new_shippings, $s_item);

            }
            $z_object["shipping_methods"] = null;
            $z_object["shipping_methods"] = $new_shippings;
            array_push($new_delivery_zones, $z_object);

        }

        $correct_zone = null;
        foreach ($new_delivery_zones as $zone) {
            foreach ($zone["zone_locations"] as $location) {
                 $splits = explode(":",$location-> code);
                 if(count($splits) > 1){
                     $country = $splits[0];
                     $code = $splits[1];
                     if($country == $country && $code == $state ){
                         $correct_zone = $zone;
                     }
                 }
            }
        }
        if($correct_zone == null)
            return $correct_zone;

        $package['destination']['country'] = $country;
        $package['destination']['state'] = (int) $state;
        $package['destination']['country'] = $country;
        $new_shipping_method = Array();
        foreach ($correct_zone["shipping_methods"] as $shipping_method) {
            if (class_exists($shipping_method["id"])) {
                $class = new $shipping_method["id"]();
                $class->calculate_shipping_for_package($package);

                foreach ($class->rates as $rate) {
                    array_push($shipping_method["rates"], Array(
                        "cost" => $rate->cost,
                        "label" => $rate->label,
                        "method_id" => $rate->method_id
                    ));
                }
//                error_log(print_r($class->rates, true));
                array_push($new_shipping_method, $shipping_method);
            }else{
                array_push($new_shipping_method, $shipping_method);
            }
        }
        $correct_zone["shipping_methods"] = $new_shipping_method;

        return $correct_zone;
    }
```

and I'm reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405929/woocommerce-shipping-api-functions)

BUT I did not understand where the problem is, Because it does not work properly and its calculated prices do not match post plugins.

Please Please Please give me the correct code
thank you very much